# Cannot logout from facebook with logoutURL in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, facebook, codeigniter, facebook-login

I know there are many many topics with this problem, and believe me, I've went through all of them. I can't get this to work.

What I want is for a global logout method, which kills both my own website session and facebook's (if there is one).

Here it is:

```
public function logout() {
    $logoutFB = false;
    $logoutURL = "";

    $this->load->library("facebook", $this->params['facebook'] );
    $fbuser = $this->facebook->getUser();

    if( $fbuser ) {
        $logoutFB = true;
        try {
            $fbuser = $this->facebook->api('/me');
            $logoutURL = $this->facebook->getLogoutUrl( array('next'=>base_url()) );
        } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
            error_log($e);
            $fbuser = null;
        }
    }

    $this->session->sess_destroy();
    delete_cookie('DoacoesUserCookie'); //TODO colocar como param

    if( $logoutFB ) {
        redirect( $logoutURL );
    }
}
```

But I can't get the `logoutURL` to work. I tried many different approaches. Calling `session_destroy()` and `facebook->destroySession()`. Nothing seems to work. When I call the URL it just opens facebook and there's nothing I can do to log me out of facebook, unless I go there and delete my app.

Any hints?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to unset session with the help of `unset($_SESSION)` and then destroy session `session_destroy();` or pass null in access token  `. $this->facebook->setAccessToken('');`